# Pull from sub-document belonging to an array of sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a QA-like project.

The current model for my questions looks like this:

```
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
  answers: [{
    content:String,
    .
    .
    .
    votes: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
  }]
});
```

As each user is entitled to more than 1 vote per question, I am trying to `$pull` all of the votes that the user voted for in a question upon an event using `Model#update`.

The following is my code:

```
  Event.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$pull: {'answers.votes': req.user.id}}).execAsync()
  .catch(err => {
    handleError(res, err);
  }).then(num => {
    if(num === 0) { return res.send(404).end(); }
  }).then(() => {exports.show(req,res);});
```

But I received the error of 'cannot use the part (..) to traverse the element'.

Is my query/update incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{$pull: {'answers.votes': req.user.id}}` is not the right way of using `$pull`, use `{$pull: {answers:{votes: req.user.id}}}` instead.

Try the following code:-

```
 Event.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$pull: {answers:{votes: req.user.id}}}).execAsync()
 .catch(err => 
  {
     handleError(res, err);
  }).then(num => 
  {
     if(num === 0) 
     { return res.send(404).end(); }
  }).then(() => {exports.show(req,res);});
```

Refer [$pull-doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) to know how to use it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It works great! Thanks! I think I am still confused about the usage of operators. But I'll look it up more. Thanks again!